# Why won't my purchased YouTube videos play anymore on Android?

Tags: youtube

I have a Motorola Turbo 2 Android. My purchased YouTube videos will no longer play. I get the following error on the screenshot below. Can anyone give me directions on how to fix this problem?

Thanks for your help.[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: There are  [5 solutions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cB_FaiFcHyc) mentioned in this you tube video

Comment: I saw that video. But isn't he using an iPhone? It looks like one. However, the title says Android. Let me give it another shot.